# MQTT publish with Qos 2 when subscriber is not connected

Tags: c, mqtt

I am publishing message with Qos=2, retain message=false and clean session=true.
If my subscriber is offline it is not getting Qos 2 messages when it comes to online again. But publisher successfully gets PUBREC and PUBCOMP

Comment: what is the question? what MQTT implementation / service do you use?

Comment: I am using hive mq websocket.

Answer (score 5):

It's the MQTT protocol specification and doesn't depend on the broker you are using.
The publisher is able to publish to the broker and for this reason it receives PUBREC and PUBCOMP because the delivery from publisher to broker is completed.
Between publisher and subscriber you have the broker in the middle so two contracts : publisher to broker, broker to subscriber. These contracts are independent each other.

Then you have retain message = false and clean session = true and it means that if there is no subscribers for the topic, the published message is just lost.
Consider a couple of things :

- the retain message flag can be used for "storing" the latest message on a topic, so that when a subscriber subscribes, it will receive such a message
- the clean session flag is for enabling broker to save susbcriptions and all messages when the subscriber is offline

I don't know your scenario but :

- if you want that the offline subscriber receives latest published message when it comes online for a topic, set retain message = true
- if you want that the broker saves all messages for an offline subscriber for all its subscriptions use clean session = false. Coming back online, the subscriber will be also able to avoid re-subscribe all topics because they are hold by broker.

Comment: can publisher know that the message is successfully received by the subscriber?

Comment: no it's not possible, it's about "brokerd messaging". You could set up an infrastructure on top of the protocol for having something like that : it means having the subscriber publishing a sort of ACK message to a topic and having the initial producer being a subscriber for that topic. But of course ... you have always the same problem, the subscribers doesn't know if publisher has received the ACK ;)